# Ошибка при установке pyinstaller на этапе подготовки wheel metadata

Tags: pip, pyinstaller

При установке pyinstaller каждый раз выдается ошибка на этапе "Preparing wheel metadata":

> ```
> Preparing wheel metadata ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\users\денис.my_comp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\денис.my_comp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\6C4A~1.MY_\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgel6fqwr'
>     cwd: C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i6u_allp\pyinstaller
> ```

Подробный вывод:

```
C:\Users\Денис.my_comp>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.0.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\денис.my_comp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\денис.my_comp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\6C4A~1.MY_\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgel6fqwr'
         cwd: C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i6u_allp\pyinstaller
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Денис.my_comp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-acf7g9ck\pyinstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\денис.my_comp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\денис.my_comp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\6C4A~1.MY_\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgel6fqwr' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

Comment: Отформатируйте команду и ошибки нормально

Comment: Возможно что проблема в русских буквах в пути к профилю пользователя. Нет ли у вас похожих проблем с установкой других пакетов?

Comment: Попробуйте создать в windows нового пользователя с именем, содержащим только латиницу, либо воспользоваться [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)